# How to display Text file on clicking button in html

Tags: php, html

I have four text files and I want to display it on the browser using the buttons I want to create four buttons when click on the 1st button first text should open. Please help me out from this I'm new to HTML and PHP.

Comment: What do you have done so far ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To do this you need to read about php file functions.**

Refer this link - http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Try below code:

```
<h2>Click</h2>
<form action="" method="post">
    <button name="click" class="click">Click me!</button>
</form>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['click']))
    {
        $filename = "test.txt";
        $before_editing = file_get_contents($filename);

    ?>
<!--this is for display in table-->
<table border="1"><tr><td><?php echo "Content of the file " . $filename . " before editing: " . $before_editing . "<br>"; ?></td></tr></table>
<!-- this is for display in single-->
    <?php
        echo "Content of the file " . $filename . " before editing: " . $before_editing . "<br>";
        file_put_contents($filename, "test test test test test");
        $after_editing = file_get_contents($filename);
        echo "Content of the file " . $filename . " after editing: " . $after_editing . "<br>";
    }
    ?>
```

**You can replace your file name to "test.txt" as i am just giving example to you.**

Comment: Thank You very much Manthan !!! i have one more request is it possible after clicking button data can be display in table format?? if yes could you please guide me ??

Comment: yes you can pass table format html in echo of the code where i have display the content of the file .

Comment: i have tried in this way but still data is not displaying table format<?php

echo '<table border="1">';
if(isset($_POST['click']))
{
    $filename = "incomingfinal.txt";
    $before_editing = file_get_contents($filename);
    echo "Content of the file " . $filename . " before editing: " . $before_editing . "<br>";
    file_put_contents($filename, "2");
    $after_editing = file_get_contents($filename);
    echo "Content of the file " . $filename . " after editing: " . $after_editing . "<br>";
}
echo '</table>';
?>

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you dont need to necessarily read the file on the triggered action of clicking a button. If you are already reading the file, load it into a hidden HTML element, like a `<div>`, then use Javascript to show that on the click of the button.

PHP:

```
$myFile = "file.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
    $theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
    fclose($fh);
    echo '<div id="hidden_content" style="display:none">'.$theData.'</div>';
```

HTML Link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="show_content()">Show it!</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function show_content(){
    document.getElementByID('hidden_content').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Or you can read the data dynamically using the ajax and show it on the page.

Comment: Might be a bit much reading 4 files into memory depending on how big they are.